CSS: Ancho máximo de un contenedor en función del ancho que necesite su hermano
Tengo el siguiente código:


.song__texts {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  width: 405px;
}

.song__ranking {
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}

.song__rym-data {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.dots {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dots:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
<div class="song__texts">

  <div class="song__ranking">1</div>

  <div class="song__rym-data">

    <div class="song__names dots">
      Luna park de …And You Will Know Us By The Trail of Dead
    </div>

    <div class="song__location dots">
      Austin (EEUU)
    </div>

    <div class="song__album dots">
      De su LP The century of self
    </div>

  </div>

</div>



Ambos trozos de código son versiones simplificadas de la realidad, y los border se utilizan sólo con funciones didácticas.

Para que la clase dots funcione y trunque los textos, el div song__rym-data ha de tener un max-width; sin embargo, dado que el número varía de 1 a 15 -y además cuando es 2 o 12 necesito darle a song__ranking un margin-right adicional porque con el tipo de fuente que uso el número 2 es muy alargado-, dicho max-width no es constante sino que necesita adaptarse al ancho que adopte el div de song__ranking al objeto de que entre ambos siempre sumen los 405 píxeles que tiene su padre song__texts de width -y song__rym-data ni se desborde ni se quede corto-.
¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto -ajustar el max-width dinámicamente- sin recurrir a JS?
EDICIÓN: dots adjunta un hover con overflow: visible de manera que cuando se pase por encima de un truncado, se revele el texto.

Solo te hace fala agregar overflow: hidden; en el selector .song__rym-data
Demo:


.song__texts {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  width: 405px;
}

.song__ranking {
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}

.song__rym-data {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dots {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.song__rym-data:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
<div class="song__texts">

  <div class="song__ranking">1</div>

  <div class="song__rym-data">
    <div class="song__names dots">
      Luna park de …And You Will Know Us By The Trail of Dead
    </div>
    <div class="song__location dots">
      Austin (EEUU)
    </div>
    <div class="song__album dots">
      De su LP The century of self
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Esto funciona genial pero me ha recordado que he simplificado demasiado el ejemplo y que dots tiene un hover para revelar el truncado cuando se pasa el ratón por encima. Voy a editar el mensaje original.

Bueno, creo que con añadirle ese mismo hover a song__rym-data serviría.

Hola Javier, cosas que pasan  . Con respecto al hover... todo depende del contexto y lo que ocurre al sacar el overflow: hidden. PD: deberías cambiar .dots:hover por .song__rym-data:hover

Sí, ya está arreglado y funciona como quiero, muchas gracias, llevaba días dándole vueltas al dichoso max-width y no hacía falta.
